# shopify landing page on Unbounce which will allow visitors to add the products to the cart

Tags: shopify, unbounce

I am creating a landing page on Unbounce which will allow visitors to add the products to the cart.

Points already achieved:

- Created a landing page
- Setup products showcase
- Processed Add to cart functionality

Points to achieve:

- Redirecting the checkout from Unbounce landing page to Shopify's custom checkout using React routes and product information using GET parameters. Currently, when proceeded with checkout on Unbounce, it is redirecting to the traditional checkout of shopify store

Insights about checkout process on Shopify store -

- A custom checkout for shopify, which works on React Routes and Laravel API calls for adding products to cart
- Customers are presented with different delivery options after submitting the shipping address
- Once selected the preferred shipping options, customers are asked for the payment for a successful order

Comment: What you are trying to achieve exactly ? Create Shopify Checkout from your React App and then redirect to it on Shopify store ? Or do you need complete custom checkout process in your React app ?

Comment: I have the complete custom checkout functionality already developed for the shopify store, there I want to redirect from Unbounce Landing Page - to process the checkout within React App.

Answer (score -1):

You should provide the code which you've tried so far.
Though here is a solution if you want to redirect from one page to another in React:

Use 'react-router-dom':

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,
 Redirect,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

And to navigate from one page to another, use following code:

```
function Routes(){
    return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
           <Route path="/" component = {CurrentPage}>
           <Redriect from='/blog/' to="/tutorials/" />           
           <Route path="/tutorials/" component={LandingPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: this solution is irrelevant - as I have not asked for redirection within the react app, I have asked for redirection from an Unbounce landing page to our react app

Comment: Share your code, whatsoever you've tried so far. I or any other dev here will try to figure it out and will post the solution for the same.